# T/F :If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , then $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ have no nonzero-vectors in common

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the follwing statements true/false?

$1.$If $W$ is a subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , then $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ have no nonzero-vectors in common

$2.$If $W$ is a subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , then $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ have no zero-vectors in common

My attempt : I think both  statements $1)$ and $2)$ are  true because $W^{\perp}=\mathbb{R}^n -W$

Comment: If both are true, the two **subspaces** have *nothing* in common..? How does that make you feel? (The main problem here is that your definition of $W^\perp$ is wrong.)

Comment: The first statement is true, because would there be $0 \ne v \in W \cap W^\perp$ then we would have $0 = \langle v, v \rangle > 0$ because of the fact that "v is orthogonal to itself" and the properties of the inner product.
For the second statement, think about what prets wrote.

Comment: Let $x \in W \cap W^{\perp}$. Then $(x|x) =||x||_2^2=0$, hence $x=0.$ Here $( \cdot| \cdot) $ denotes the usual inner product on $ \mathbb R^n.$

Comment: @prets $W^{\perp}$ denote complement orthogonal

Comment: Yes, but orthogonal complement is not the same thing as complement. $W^\perp = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \,|\, \langle x, y \rangle = 0 \text{ for all $y \in W$ }\}$.

Comment: @prets orthogonal complement $\implies$  complement  subspace

Comment: Complement subspace does not make sense. A subspace **has** to include $0$. If you remove zero (e.g. by taking the complement of a subspace) you simply do not have a subspace, period.

Comment: okay @prets Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $W^\perp$ is not $\mathbb R^n - W$, it is $W^\perp = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \,|\, \langle x, y \rangle = 0 \text{ for all $y \in W$ }\}$. This is an important distinction, since the **set complement** of a subspace is **never** a subspace (for one, it removes $0$, which is required for a subspace). Here by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ I mean an inner product/dot product.

With this in mind: 1) is true, since if $x \in W \cap W^\perp$ we must have $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ by definition of $W^\perp$, but the only element satisfying $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ is $x = 0$ (why?).

This also tells us for free that 2) is not true, since we just demonstrated that the intersection contains (only) $0$.
Note however that even without the above argument 2) **has** to be false, for reasons of $W$ and $W^\perp$ being subspaces, as in the first paragraph.